# Watson Discovery only returning 10 results when I query the whole collection

Tags: java, ibm-watson, watson-discovery

I'm trying to query the collection of documents with a wildcard, using Java API
code as follows

```
QueryOptions.Builder queryBuilder = new QueryOptions
            .Builder(environmentId, collectionId);
            queryBuilder.query("text:*");
            QueryResponse queryResponse = discovery.query(queryBuilder.build()).execute().getResult();
```

the result I have parsed into a json file however it only returns 10 out of the

```
{
  "matching_results": 17,
...
}
```

17 results,

how do I get all 17 result to display in Json format?

Comment: I don't know the API but it seems the results are paginated and you're only getting the first 10 because of some pagination default parameter, that I'd search and modify inside your QueryOptions class (and if not found, inside the discovery service itself)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the answer on the docs that I missed:

```
queryBuilder.query("text:*").count(17);
```

Comment: documented in the API reference at https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/discovery-data?code=java#query